# Symfony2.1 Serve Upload

Tags: download, symfony-2.1

i have a question about serving files with Symfony 2.1

```
public function exampleFileAction(){
    $response = new Response();

    $d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'File.xls');

    $response->setContent(file_get_contents('../uploads/Bundle/Files/File.xls'));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);
    return $response;
}
```

My code above is working fine, but is it the actual way to do it like this? 
And is it good to get the file with file_get_contents?

Thanks
tny

Comment: You really should accept Damien's answer as it is the correct solution - karma dude

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT March 2013**:

This response should not be followed for big files, 
there is a new player in the game: https://github.com/igorw/IgorwFileServeBundle

It support SendFile to delegate the file download to Apache/Ngnix and this is MUCH better.

**EDIT May 2013**:

Awesome news: a build in solution is now available in the core: [BinaryFileResponse](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/BinaryFileResponse.php).

---

**OLD response:**

There is a new Response class named `StreamedResponse`, 
it does exactly what you are trying to do, but is more memory efficient and is well handled by the kernel.

> StreamedResponse represents a streamed HTTP response.
>   A StreamedResponse uses a callback for its content.
>   The callback should use the standard PHP functions like echo
>   to stream the response back to the client. The flush() method
>   can also be used if needed.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response

So for a large file you can do it without file_get_content:

```php
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    $name = 'bigfile.pdf';
    $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
    fpassthru($fp);
});
$d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'foo.pdf');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);
$response->send();
```

Comment: I can't get to serve a pdf file stored as blob in mysql instead of a file in a directory.

Comment: Don't forget use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Damien's solution to work in the controller.

Here is what I got to work:

```
<?php
...
return new StreamedResponse(
  function () use ($file) {
    readfile($file);
  }, 200, array(
            'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="filename.png"')
);
```

Credit: http://ailoo.net/2013/03/stream-a-file-with-streamedresponse-in-symfony/